# How to read an argument at a server from a telnet client in socket programming c

Tags: c, sockets, telnet

Here's the scenario:

I connect to a server using telnet utility in Linux. After the connection is established client should enter and argument which should be read by a server.

Here's the server code:

```
int main(void)
{
int new_fd;
char *string;
// Establish the connection

if (send(new_fd, "Enter Command: ", 15, 0) == -1)
            perror("send");  

// Here I want to accept the argument from the server
return 0;
}
```

When I telnet into server using: `telnet servername portnumber`
client receives : `Enter Command:` in front of which I want to type in the argument.
for e.g. `Enter Command: Hey There!`

All I want to do is read `Hey There!` store it in `string` at the server and print it. How can I do that?

Comment: You're still using telnet!? Don't you realize that it sends your username and password and everything else in plain text?

Comment: Thank you, but it's for the learning purpose not professional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To receive anything over a socket you'll need to call `recv` and check that for as long as the return value is larger than 0, you write the incoming data to wherever you wish.

```
 ssize_t recv(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags);
```

> These calls return the number of bytes received, or -1 if an error occurred. The return value will be 0 when the peer has performed an orderly shutdown.

[From here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv)